# New Grails domain class is not creating a table in the database

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I just created a new grails domain class on a project I just started working on. I know the datasources are setup correctly since we already have a bunch of domain classes that are updating to the database just fine.

The error I get:

```
Caused by BatchUpdateException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I tried running DBMUpdate but that also did not create the table.

Is there something I'm missing with creating domain classes? Do I need to change something in the changelog ? Any advise would be helpful!

Comment: what's dbCreate (in the per-environment configuration) set to?

Comment: There is no dbcreate, I'm assuming this means that grails will not create the tables automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to add `dbCreate = "update"` to your DataSource.groovy.  A better thing would be to use the database-migrations plugin for your app.

Regarding manually creating tables, the convention grails following by default is to underscore camelcase. For example, given the following domains:

```
class User {
  String firstName
  String lastName 
  static hasMany = [addresses: Address]
}

class Address {

  static belongsTo = [user: User]
}
```

You would end up with the following tables:

```
user
---------
id
version
first_name
last_name
---------

address
---------
id
version
user_id
---------
```

Comment: Thank you, turns out the application was using the database-migration plugin so I just generated a changelog file using dbm-generate-gorm-changelog changelog.groovy and then ran dbm-update and all tables were created. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try running...

```
grails export-schema
```

This will uses Hibernate's `SchemaExport` tool to generate DDL or export the schema for the entire database. From that file, you can grab the lines for the missing table.

Check out the [Grails Quick Reference](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Command%20Line/schema-export.html) for more details on the command.

Comment: Using grails version 3.2.8, the correct command is `grails schema-export` (I ran the command and it gave me this suggestion)